Show statement about weight updates in adaboost
Assume you are given a training set
$$
T = \{(x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_n, y_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d \times \{-1, +1\}
$$
of labelled instances. Prove, that over $b$, that the weight updates
$$
w_i^{(b+1)} = \frac{w_i^{(b)} \exp(-\alpha_b y_i h_b(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_j^{(b)} \exp(-\alpha_b y_j h_b(x_j))}
$$
as the formula in Adaboost it can be written as
$$
w_i^{(b+1)} = \frac{\exp(-y_i f_b(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-y_j f_b(x_j))},
$$
where $h_b$ is the weak learner fitted in boosting round $b$,$\alpha_b$ the importance of $h_b$, and
$$
f_b = \sum_{p \leq b} \alpha_p h_p.
$$
I think I should use induction, but I'm not sure how to show it, but think it make sense for b=1. If there miss inforation let me know
